# Como posso fazer uma janela de permissão igual do facebook!

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

eu tenho um site de noticias e não sei como fazer esse sisteminha!
como fazer aquela janelinha de permissao de acesso aos dados igual do facebook.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo so SOpt. Sua pergunta não está clara. Tente explicar melhor.

Comment: Para qualquer coisa que envolva o facebook, faça uma integração com base nas apis deles. (https://developers.facebook.com/), veja mais sobre que parte deseja usar e depois reformule sua pergunta.